# Google Map is not loading completely on page Load

Tags: google-maps

Am implementing google maps in my Aspx application. The following code works fine in html. When am trying to implement in a CSHtml it does not show the map completely on load. I used the following code in my aspx to load the map.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAuPsJpk3MBtDpJ4G8cqBnjRRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQCzVBXTx2DYyXGsTOxpWhvIG7Djw"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/uds/api?file=uds.js&amp;v=1.0" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="gmlocalsearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

    // Create and Center a Map
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

    // bind a search control to the map, suppress result list
    map.addControl(new google.maps.LocalSearch(), new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_RIGHT, new GSize(10,20)));
  }
}
GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

</script>
```

Img for partial loaded map

I Uploaded the screen shot in the follwing URL http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/7/mapdk.jpg/.

How to load the map completely on page load itself in my CSHtml page? any fix or solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The image you have linked to shows a small map, so does your question...

> How to load the map completely on page load itself in my CSHtml page

...mean that you want the map to fill out the whole page?

Using your example code that you have above (I am assuming you put that in the  of the HTML document), and given that you have a div somewhere `<div id="map_canvas"></div>`, I think that all you are missing is the CSS to define what size you want the map. For instance,

```
<style type="text/css">
  #map_canvas { width: 800px; height: 800px; }
</style>
```

The Google Maps API will render the map to whatever the size of the map's containing div is.

Also see this [Google Maps API Page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Their example will render a map that fills the whole page:

```
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
```

Comment: No i don't want to fill the map in whole page. I am loading the map inside a popup window.                                                      I tried above your solution, but still i'm getting this same issue.

Comment: So are you trying to load the map before someone hits the popup window?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you are using to load it? For instance, what does the link look like that loads the map? Are you referencing another HTML page, or something link `<a href="..." target="_blank">Map</a>`?